# How to get balance using wallet adapters and connections?

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I have taken the standard code from Solana for the wallet-adapter implementation which works to connect to the wallet. But I cannot get the balance to work. I tried connection.getBalance() but the method is not found. Has anyone a suggestion?

```
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletModalProvider, WalletMultiButton } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import React, { FC, ReactNode, useMemo } from 'react';

require('./App.css');
require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

const App: FC = () => {
    return (
        <Context>
            <Content />
        </Context>
    );
};
export default App;

const Context: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    // The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

    // You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
    const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
            new UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter(),
        ],
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        [network]
    );

    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>{children}</WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
};

const Content: FC = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <WalletMultiButton />
        </div>
    );
};
```

I then tried -

```
const  connection  = useConnection();
     const  publicKey  = useWallet();
     const [balance, setBalance] = useState<string | null>(null);
           const fetchBalance = async () => {
               const balance1 = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);
               console.log("balance == "+ balance1);
               setBalance(balance1);
           };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBalance();
    }, [connection, publicKey]);
```

The error is getBalance is not available on connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to deconstruct `publicKey` from `useWallet` like this:

```
     const  { publicKey } = useWallet();
```

Take a look at the dapp scaffold:
https://github.com/solana-labs/dapp-scaffold/blob/6d441f295f2036994321ff5281105d009a17fd73/src/views/home/index.tsx#L25

Comment: I also added {connection}=useConnection(); and a test is needed before getBalance to test for null.